# Filter a pandas DataFrame using keys from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pd.DataFrame:

```
AllData = 
a@a.6   f@s.2   c@c.2   d@w.4   k@a.3
1       8       3       3       8
4       4       7       4       3
6       8       9       1       6
3       4       5       6       1
7       6       0       8       1
```

And I would like to create a new pd.DataFrame with only the columns whose names are keys in the following dictionary:

```
my_dict={a@a.6 : value1, c@c.2 : value2, d@w.4 : value5}
```

So the new DataFrame would be:

```
FilteredData = 
a@a.6   c@c.2   d@w.4   
    1       3       3
    4       7       4
    6       9       1
    3       5       6
    7       0       8
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I have tried to use:

```
FilteredData = AllData.filter(regex=my_dict.keys)
```

but unsurprisingly, this didn't work. Any suggestions/advice welcome

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this without the filter method at all like this:

```
FilteredData = AllData[my_dict.keys()]
```

Comment: Is there a difference in the way these two methods are executed?

Comment: I'm actually not sure the difference in what happens behind the scene here, but someone here surely must?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas dataframes have a method called filter that will return a new dataframe. Try this

```
FilteredData = AllData.filter(items=my_dict.keys())
```

Comment: No I meant `items` to itmes, but I understand what you are saying.

Comment: What is the difference between this method and the one proposed by @bdiamante?

Comment: @user1083734 there are differences however I am relatively new to pandas and don't think I can explain them very well. You can look at the DataFrame source on github and see for yourself. The [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L1986) is the "magic" method that bdiamante uses and [filter](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L3005) is the method I use.